# Black screen on 4.4.0-64 and 4.4.0-66

Tags: kernel, graphics

I can load up on 4.4.0-62 but not 4.4.0-64 or 4.4.0-66. I get a black screen when I load up. I've had a look on these forums and not sure if it is a kernel or graphics problem or something else. Upgrading doesn't seem to make any difference. Loading it up in recovery mode doesn't work either.

My knowledge of ubuntu/computers is limited (I just had to look up what a Kernel was) so not even sure if I'm asking the right question. What are the best commands to try and diagnose the problem?

- CPU: AMD phenom 11x4 970 Processor x4 (32-bit)
- RAM: 15.8 GiB
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD CAICOS (DRM 2.43.0/4.4.0-62-generic, LLVM 3.8.0)
- Disk: 475.2GB

Comment: Just use kernel v4.4.0-62 then. Do you have a particular reason to use these newer kernel revisions instead of v4.4.0-62? Other than that you should report this as a regression bug [on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/). The package maintainers there will guide you in the diagnose of the issue. Bug reports are off topic on AskUbuntu.